# Moving input cells to appendix in Jupyter when exporting to HTML

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter

Input cells on my notebooks contain a lot of relevant code and some graph setup/boilerplate code that I'd like to be able to move to an appendix section when exporting to HTML, while still having the output show up in the correct order. How can this be done?

Most of the solutions I was able to find deal with removing the input cells altogether and sometimes selectively, but not moving any cells.